# Selecting Member Function Using Enable_if

Tags: templates, c++11

I have a class which I need to perform different action based upon the value supplied in the template. But I'm getting an error message "prototype does not match any in class..."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<int t>
struct A
{
    template<typename EqualTwo>
    void test();
};

template<int t>
template<typename std::enable_if<t == 2>::value>
void A<t>::test()
{
    cout << "T is equal to two.";
}

template<int t>
template<typename std::enable_if<t != 2>::value>
void A<t>::test()
{
    cout << "T is not equal to two.";
}

int main() {
    A<5> five;
    A<2> two;
    cout << five.test() << endl;
    cout << two.test() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is messed up, probably what you want to do is the following:

```
template<int t, typename Enable = void>
struct A;

template<int t>
struct A<t, typename std::enable_if<t == 2>::type> {
  void test() { cout << "T is equal to two." << endl; }
};

template<int t>
struct A<t, typename std::enable_if<t != 2>::type> {
  void test() { cout << "T is not equal to two." << endl; }
};
```

and in `main()`:

```
int main() {
  A<5> five;
  A<2> two;
  five.test();
  two.test();
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e84a5bef3da4706)

Edit:

Unfortunately, you can't specialize a member function of a template class unless you specialize the class itself.

You could however do the following:

```
template<int t>
struct A {
  void test() {
    if(t == 2) {
      cout << "T is equal to two." << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "T is not equal to two" << endl;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In my real code, not the example, I have many other member variables and functions which do not need to be specialized. Only this one function. Is there not a way to switch between that one function?

Comment: @JadziaMD You can also use inheritance: a base class with common code and as many derived as you need. see [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffc4a858f36cd2b2) based on primary answer